# LG Optimus P500 system essential apps deleted accidentally

Tags: adb, restore, lg-optimus-one

I recently rooted my LG P500 successfully.

But after that, in removing some bloatware I deleted some of my system apps.

After that my notifications area is visible but my home screen and apps screen are not visible.

Also, I performed a factory reset to the phone. So the USB debugging is gone, so cannot connect through `adb`.

Please help!

Comment: If you performed a factory reset, it would restore the phone to its default state as if left the factory, at this point, the phone should be ok and booting normally, **read** you will have to re-root the device again, so what's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I got this :) . Everything was working normally, but only the system default packages were deleted. I used [LG MOBILE SUPPORT TOOL](http://www.lg.com/us/support/product-help/CT10000003-CT10000027-1379712374470) and update it again, which brings the phone default ROM to its original state. Thanks for the reply.